# Cannot print out decimal numbers upto 6 in a void function.the value are correct checked by debugging.the problem is with the output

Tags: c++, for-loop, double, decimal

```
**The void function automatically rounds off the value of a,b,c and prints out 0 instead of 0.5,0.33,0.166. I have checked the value of num1,num2,num3 and g they are correct just the problem is with the rounding off of the decimals of a,b and c.The setprecision function is also not working.
```

The simple concept is when the user gives input as array we have to count the number of positive no.,number of negative no.,no of zero's(stored in num1,num2,num3 respectively).   **

```
  void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
   int g = arr.size();
   int num1=0; // Initialized value of num1.
   int num2=0; // Initialized value of num2.
   int num3=0;  // Initialized value of num3.

   for(int t=0;t<g;t++){
      if(arr[t]>0){
       num1++; 
      }
      else{
       if(arr[t]<0){
           num2++;
       }
      if(arr[t]==0){
          num3++; 
      }
      }
   }
           const  double a = num1/g; // made const due to the automatic rounding-off //
           const  double b = num2/g;  // made const due to the automatic rounding-off //
           const  double c = num3/g;   // made const due to the automatic rounding-off //
 
     cout << setprecision(6) << a << b << c; // The problem is with this line
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want the code to have an output of numbers; bc in which case, you need to sysout variable num1, num2, and num3.

Comment: first you explain full form of bc.Then,I do not want to print out num1 num2 num3 i want to get value of (num1/g) and (num2/g)    and ( num3/g)

Comment: Bc means because, ok I think I understand the issue. You are storing num1/g, num2/g, and num3/g as double a,b, and c. But, num1, num2, and num3 are ints not doubles. So you must use type conversion on num1, num2, and num3. 

So prior to storing num1/g in double a, you should do this; double x=double(num1); and then you can say double a= x/g because x is num1 and num1 is a double now. Do the same conversion for num2 and num3 as well

Comment: ok i tried by not declaring a variable a, b,c and doing directly cout << num1/g.

Comment: but it gives the same answer

Comment: I hope my above explanation made sense, im a beginner and I’m trying to understand your question, but I might not because I am new to StackOverflow

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. So apparently C++ does not consider integer/integer form a fraction. We have to declare num1 as double which it is not....